# Cordova 11 and Android 12 upgrade

Tags: android, cordova

I have an older application, which I inherited support for,  that needed a minor change.   The Google Play store required that the target SDK be updated from 30 to 31.  But the version of cordova did not support that sdk version, so I had to update cordova to 11 as well.

But now that I did that , none of the ajax calls that require session persistence work.  Does anyone know how to make https calls that will use the same session.   The Server side is returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and the same calls work in chrome browser.

I tried setting the

but that doesn't help.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I tried setting the  but that doesn't help.

It looks like each request is always sent as a new session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried settings these preferences to send from https from the webview ?

```
<preference name="scheme" value="https" />
<preference name="hostname" value="com.yourdomain" />
```

And then allow that domain on the server side for you `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`